# nhibernate session strange behavior

Tags: c#, nhibernate, session

i have an app with fluent nhibernate mappings..

when i start the app first time and initiate a session and a configuration an a session factory for the first time i see in the console that the session do some updates inserts and select on my mapped class

any one can explain this please..?

i see stuff like AbstractEntityPersister.Insert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the application first starts NHibernate creates static SQL for the CRUD operations of all your entities and caches them so that it doesn't have to create them for every request.